# Wordpress bootstrap Menu Walker

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to make a Menu With Dropdown for a wordpress website in my localhost, and i was thinking to use the wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php file, also try it without. I've walk through the readme on: github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker for the navwalker file and add everythink correctly.

So the issue is that, I can not add the menu's in directly in my wordpress page, the menu choise dousn't appear.

E.g.: In my wordpress i see only the 3 options: theme, customizer and editor, not the 'menus'.

functies.php

```
require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');

register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'THEMENAME' ),
) );
```

header.php

```
         <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );
    ?>
```

error 1: [wpb.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr0tY.png)

When i also put `require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');` in wordpress/wp-includes map in file: template.php it shows a second error, see image [wpb2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxZm6.png)

Can someone help me with these issues i'm facing? i appreciate it.

**UPDATE: I've solve the problem**, it's important to name the funtion file: funtions.php and not: functies.php

Comment: Don't require the navwalker and register the nav menu at the very top of the functions file. You need to initialize your theme before doing that. Try placing it at the bottom.

Comment: check the documentation how to use this at

Comment: What do you mean with initialize the theme ? I've read the documentation on: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus , i've the same but dousn't work...

Comment: I just mean don't put it at the very top. I typically call the `register_nav_menus()` function in the `after_theme_setup` hook. That may not be the case for you though, as the nav-menu.php file is called before the functions.php file is loaded I believe. When you call `wp_nav_menu()`, change the `menu` parameter to `'Primary Menu'` so it reads like `wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Primary Menu', ...));`

Comment: I created a gist for you to check out how I do it: https://gist.github.com/TylerB24890/76997651b93f36cf146d07b1dc3dfdc9

Comment: I've did what you said, but i've still the same errors. Is it necessary to remove ` require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php'); ` from template.php or keep it?

Comment: I see now in my navigation bar a button: Add a menu, when i pace your code in myn header.php paste. But the wordpress-back end dousn't show the 'menu' option, and also when i click on the button Add a menu. It says that: " This theme does not support navigation menus or widgets. " How can i fix this?